# gitlab-ci : Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation, mysql, gitlab

I am using "mysql 5.7" in my "gitlab-ci" file and use "apt-get -y install mysql-client" to install sql client but it is always giving me error.

```
ERROR : "Package mysql-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source".
```

This script is running on gitlab pipeline and that is were I am getting this error. When I push the code to my branch, a pipeline runs which installs all the dependencies first where this fails.

Comment: You haven't told us your flavor/release of Ubuntu but I see the following `mysql-client` package/releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mysql-client) so I'd check your release, sources and then mirror you use (*is it up-to-date, or reasonably so*; https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). You've provided us little, so I can't provide more.

Comment: I am writing these scripts in the **gitlab-ci.yml** file for automated testing of my code. I am using **golang 1.12**. These errors come up when I push my code and pipeline runs on gitlab

Answer (score 7):

I happen to run into the same error. In my case i'm using docker with python:3.7 which used to be based on debian stretch but is now updated to debian buster (10). This newer debian version doesn't have the package mysql-client -> https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=mysql-client

Could it be that you're using docker to load golang:1.12? They actually use debian instead of ubuntu and have recently moved to debian 10. To fix this error install **default-mysql-client** instead.

*(This should be a comment but I don't have 50 rep points yet and I do believe this helps you out because of the exact timing)*

Comment: I just resolved this issue. Yes it was due to the OS version on which **GitLab Runners** were trying to run these scripts and just had to make changes to it and the thing started working fine.

Comment: Does anyone know why the name of the package changed to add 'default-' as a prefix?